# My PC has slowed down unexpectedly

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, malware, malware-detection

I am worried that my PC might be infected with malware. I am getting a lot of notifications that taskhost and svchost tried accessing some specific folder but are blocked. I have also read that taskhost could be infected easily. Taskhost and svchost look really suspicious at this very current moment and also my PC performance has slowed down a bit. Below are the screenshots of notifications that I often get.

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4S7i.png)

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCsvg.png)

[Screenshot #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlzIS.png)

Answer (score 3):

- [Scan your computer with Windows Defender](https://www.howtogeek.com/679263/how-to-scan-with-microsoft-defender-antivirus-on-windows-10/)
- Scan your computer with [MalwareBytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malwarebytes_(software))

Comment: Thanks, will try Malwarebytes.

Comment: I tried scanning my PC with MalwareBytes and it found out 26 malwares, mostly were in AppData/Local/Google/chrome. Is there anything to be worried about? Should I paste here the exact log messages? Also, I have removed Chrome.

Comment: @SuryanshuDinkar Tell MalwareBytes to delete or quarantine everything it found. When that is finished, restart the PC. Then tell MalwareBytes to scan everything again. Hopefully this time it will show that the computer has no more malware!

Comment: I did the same and it now shows that no malware found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning with Windows Defender is a very good idea.

Also look at the settings for running Windows Defender in Offline mode.

Running Windows Defender Offline can remove viruses that online WD cannot quarantine.

[image: WD Offline Scan]

.

Also make sure none of your own applications are trying to store date in Program Files or like secured folders. Virus will do this, but your apps should not.

Comment: I have tried doing it but it doesn't seem to go.

Comment: Viruses may have damaged your system. Offline scan works in both Windows 10 and Windows 11 pre-release.  You may have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Don't forget you have to restart Windows for Offline scan to work.

Comment: I tried scanning my PC with MalwareBytes and it found out 26 malwares, mostly were in AppData/Local/Google/chrome.